# Using SAS arrays to create new variables with suffix

Tags: arrays, sas

I am trying to use an array to create new variables (such as year on year and week on week change). I want to keep a naming convention so that I have say "orders" and then use the array to produce "orders_LY" and "orders_LW"

This one works (from code below)

```
 LW=lag1(figures{i});
```

though this is not what I want,

this one doesn't

```
figures{i}_LY=lag53(figures{i});


data summary_&type._&date.; 
    set summary;


    array figures {5} tv_total_orders_&type. tv_total_bookings_&type. TV_AOV_&type. total_orders_&type. total_bookings_&type. ;
    do i=1 to 5;

    LW=lag1(figures{i});
    figures{i}_LY=lag53(figures{i});


    end;
    run;
```

Comment: Create another array?

Comment: Be careful with passing an array reference to the lag function. When you code `lag1(figures{i})` the lag function only creates one queue, rather than one queue for each element of the array. So the value of tv_total_orders_&type will be written to tv_total_book_&type, etc, which is probably not what you intend.

Answer (score 2):

Joe is correct in that you can't define them on the fly, however you can create the structure that you need separately, and then define the arrays based on the existing structure.  Here's an example:

Create some variables that we want to add suffixes to:

```
data fields;
  length field $50;
  input field $;
  datalines;
orders
sold
billed
cost
gp
;
run;
```

Add the suffixes:

```
data config;
  length new_name $50;
  set fields;
  new_name = field; output;
  new_name = cats(field,'_LW'); output;
  new_name = cats(field,'_LY'); output;
  dummy=1;
run;
```

Transpose it to get the suffixed variables as column names:

```
proc transpose data=config out=trans(drop=_name_);
  id new_name;
  var dummy;
run;
```

Now you can define your arrays based on existing names.

Answer (score 1):

So, you cannot on the fly in the data step modify the array variable names.  Variable names must be known when the data step compilation occurs.

You have two options, then:

First, you could create a second array like so:

```
figures_ly {5} tv_total_orders_&type._ly tv_total_bookings_&type._ly TV_AOV_&type._ly total_orders_&type._ly total_bookings_&type._ly ;
```

(you may need to do variable attribute initialization, I don't know your data.)  This is best if you know what you need when you do the programming, and the list of variables doesn't change.

Second, you could use the macro language to define these LY variables.  This is more appropriate if you need to make changes to the variable list often and/or you don't know the list until you run the program (it is data-driven).  If that's the case you should post more information about how the list is determined to get a useful response.